# Proof using iduction: calculate sum of digits

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am having trouble to work with induction in the following case:

[image]

Beweise means prove and Hinweis is a hint.

How do I start here?

Any help is upvoted. Thank you

Comment: thank you sir, I corrected it.

Comment: Just to be sure, **q** is the sum-of-digits function?

Comment: yes and for the (amount?)

Comment: 'Beweise' means 'prove', not 'proof'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\Bbb N_{*9}^+=\{9k:k\in\Bbb N^+\}$. Thus, we can prove the result by induction on $k$. For $k=1$ we have $\mathbf{q}(9k)=\mathbf{q}(9)=9$, and certainly $9\bmod 9=0$.

For the induction step assume as your induction hypothesis that $\mathbf{q}(9k)\bmod 9=0$; you want to use this to show that $\mathbf{q}\big(9(k+1)\big)\bmod 9=0$. Here’s where you use the hint: $9(k+1)=9k+9$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{q}\big(9(k+1)\big)\bmod 9&=\mathbf{q}(9k+9)\bmod 9\\
&=\Big(\big(\mathbf{q}(9k)\bmod 9\big)+\big(\mathbf{q}(9)\bmod 9\big)\Big)\bmod 9\;.
\end{align*}$$

Can you finish the argument from here?